# CSS select element

Tags: html, css

how can I select the:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single">
```

starting from the:

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
    <label for="municipio_uf">Uf</label>
</div>
<select id="municipio_uf_id" name="municipio[uf_id]" style="display: none; " class="chzn-done">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="1">Parana</option>
    <option value="2">Sao Paulo</option>
    <option value="3">Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value="4">Mato Grosso</option>
    <option value="5">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
    <option value="6">Santa Catarina</option>
</select>
<div id="municipio_uf_id_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 265px;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single"><span>-</span>
    <div>
        <b></b>
    </div>
    </a>    
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but with CSS you can't.  You can select `chzn-single` with respect to `chzn-container` or `chzn-container-single` because that's a parent.  If that's not unique enough you'd might need to wrap this whole fragment in a div with a unique ID.

Comment: `#municipio_uf_id_chzn > a`, since `municipio_uf_id_chzn` is unique anyways

Comment: Rails automaticaly add a "field-with-errors" class to the first div when a error occurs. So this is my start point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your structure will always be exactly that way, you could use:

`div.field_with_errors + select.chzn-done + div.chzn-container a.chzn-single`

The `+` is a sibling selector, so it will only select that particular `a.chzn-single`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a descendant selector.  In your CSS:

```
#municipio_uf_id_chzn a.chzn-single
{
  ... css stuff ...
}
```

Or the adjacent sibling selector `+`.  Like this (same as Nate B's answer):

```
div.field_with_errors + #municipio_uf_id + #municipio_uf_id_chzn a.chzn-single
```

Of the two, I think descendant is the better option as ids should be unique on the page.